# how can i write my json's data into an Excel file

Tags: python, json, excel

I want to convert Json data to Excel, but I cannot transfer the internal data as I want.

Json like below

```json
data = {"INVOICES":
     
     [
         {"CODE":"20240113_16EB01_286",
          "ISEDOS":1,
          "LEGALNUMBER":"286",
          "STATUS":"I",
          "SALESTYPE":"VADELISATIS",
          "ISSUEDATE":"2024-01-13T08:47:00",
          "DUEDATE":"2024-01-20T00:00:00",
          "CREDITDAYS":7,
          "NETAMOUNT":56.6800,
          "OUTSTANDINGAMOUNT":56.6800,
          "TAXAMOUNT":15.0000,
          "TOTAL_DISCOUNT":0.27,
          "CUSTOMER":{"CODE":"368",
                      "REGISTEREDNAME":"NRKMEZ",
                      "TAXNUMBER":"201",
                      "LICENSENUMBER":"1598"},
            "POSITION":{"CODE":"D16DR01",
                        "DESCRIPTION":"01"},
            "PAYMENTS":[
                            {"CODE":"1692677759",
                             "ISSUEDATE":"2024-01-13T09:47:00",
                             "AMOUNT":77.4400,
                             "PAYMENTFORM":{"CODE":"HAVALE",
                                            "DESCRIPTION":"Havale"}},

                            {"CODE":"169267",
                             "ISSUEDATE":"2024-01-13T09:47:00",
                             "AMOUNT":27.4400,
                             "PAYMENTFORM":{"CODE":"NAKİT",
                                            "DESCRIPTION":"NAKİT"}}],



"DETAILS":[
            {"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":63,
                        "CODE":"URUN1",
                        "DESCRIPTION":"URUN1"},
            "QUANTITY":0.0,
            "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "PRICE":51.5700,
            "AVAILABILITY":0},


            {"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":64,
                        "CODE":"URUN2",
                        "DESCRIPTION":"URUN2"},
            "QUANTITY":0.0,
            "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "PRICE":51.5700,
            "AVAILABILITY":0},

{"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":57,
            "CODE":"URUN3",
            "DESCRIPTION":"URUN3"},
            "QUANTITY":0.0,
            "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
            "PRICE":51.5700,
            "AVAILABILITY":0}],
            "RETURNGOODS":None},
            {"CODE":"20240113_16EB01_0290",
             "ISEDOS":1,
             "LEGALNUMBER":"0290",
             "STATUS":"I",
             "SALESTYPE":"HHSATIS",
             "ISSUEDATE":"2024-01-13T09:47:00",
             "DUEDATE":"2024-01-13T00:00:00",
             "CREDITDAYS":0,
             "NETAMOUNT":7.4400,
             "OUTSTANDINGAMOUNT":0.0000,
             "TAXAMOUNT":7.5100,
             "TOTAL_DISCOUNT":1.34,
             "CUSTOMER":{"CODE":"6636",
                         "REGISTEREDNAME":"ARAS",
                         "TAXNUMBER":"3768",
                         "LICENSENUMBER":"1464"},
            "POSITION":{"CODE":"D16DR01",
                        "DESCRIPTION":"01"},
            "PAYMENTS":[{"CODE":"1692677759",
                         "ISSUEDATE":"2024-01-13T09:47:00",
                         "AMOUNT":7.4400,
                         "PAYMENTFORM":{"CODE":"HAVALE",
                                        "DESCRIPTION":"Havale"}}],
            "DETAILS":[
                        {"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":63,
                                    "CODE":"URUN1",
                                    "DESCRIPTION":"URUN1"},
                        "QUANTITY":0.0,
                        "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "PRICE":51.5700,
                        "AVAILABILITY":0},
                        
                        {"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":64,
                                    "CODE":"URUN2",
                                    "DESCRIPTION":"URUN2"},
                        "QUANTITY":0.0,
                        "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "PRICE":51.5700,
                        "AVAILABILITY":0},
                        
                        {"PRODUCT":{"SEQUENCE":57,
                                    "CODE":"URUN3",
                                    "DESCRIPTION":"URUN3"},
                        "QUANTITY":0.0,
                        "NETAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "GROSSAMOUNT":0.0000,
                        "PRICE":51.5700,
                        "AVAILABILITY":0}],
            "RETURNGOODS":None}]}
```

**result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0llZb.png)

When the translation is finished, the N and O columns are intertwined. What I want is the sequence in DETAILS to appear after W, and after this sequence is completed, the PAYMENT information should appear in the same row.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

from json_excel_converter import Converter 
from json_excel_converter.xlsx import Writer

with open(r'C:\Users\Asus\test\TEST\test.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())

invoices = data ['INVOICES'] 
df = pd.json_normalize(invoices)
print(invoices)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

This is my expectation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjEXl.png)

Please can anyone help me in this situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: When parsing a JSON line, why not first check if the VALUE is valid JSON, and if so, parse all inner JSON elements too, and add them to the corresponding Excel columns?

Comment: what are your tries ? ... your code does not do any thing , that means we have to write the whole code for you .>>>>> please learn the concepts that help you to deal with Excel files and try to write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution,
Maybe someone in need can benefit from it too

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def flatten_json(json_obj, prefix=''):
    flat_dict = {}
    for key, value in json_obj.items():
        new_key = f"{prefix}_{key}" if prefix else key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            flat_dict.update(flatten_json(value, new_key))
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for i, item in enumerate(value, 1):
                flat_dict.update(flatten_json(item, f"{new_key}_{i}"))
        else:
            flat_dict[new_key] = value
    return flat_dict

def flatten_payments(payments_list, prefix=''):
    flat_dict = {}
    for i, payment in enumerate(payments_list, 1):
        flat_payment = flatten_json(payment, f"{prefix}_{i}")
        flat_dict.update(flat_payment)
    return flat_dict

def flatten_details(details_list, prefix=''):
    flat_dict = {}
    for i, detail in enumerate(details_list, 1):
        flat_detail = flatten_json(detail, f"{prefix}_{i}")
        flat_dict.update(flat_detail)
    return flat_dict

def json_to_excel(json_data, excel_file):
    invoices = json_data['INVOICES']

    details_list = []
    payments_list = []
    for invoice in invoices:
        
        details = invoice.get('DETAILS', [])
        flat_details = flatten_details(details, "DETAILS")
        flat_details['INVOICE_CODE'] = invoice.get('CODE')
        details_list.append(flat_details)
     
        payments = invoice.get('PAYMENTS', [])
        flat_payments = flatten_payments(payments, "PAYMENTS")
        flat_payments['INVOICE_CODE'] = invoice.get('CODE')
        payments_list.append(flat_payments)
    
    data = pd.json_normalize(invoices)
    
    details_data = pd.DataFrame(details_list)
    payments_data = pd.DataFrame(payments_list)
    
    merged_data = pd.merge(data, details_data, left_on='CODE', right_on='INVOICE_CODE', how='left', suffixes=('', '_DETAILS'))
    
    merged_data = pd.merge(merged_data, payments_data, left_on='CODE', right_on='INVOICE_CODE', how='left', suffixes=('', '_PAYMENTS'))
    
    merged_data.to_excel(excel_file, index=False, engine='openpyxl')

with open(r'test.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

excel_file_path = 'output.xlsx'

json_to_excel(json_data, excel_file_path)

print(f'Excel dosyası: {excel_file_path}')
```